# How to work with file descriptors stored in variables?

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh, io-redirection, file-descriptors

For example, if I assign

```
TWO=2
```

...the following fails (with `date: invalid date '2'`):

```
date >> logfile $TWO>&1
```

Of course, I can always do

```
eval "date >> logfile $TWO>&1"
```

Is this the only way to run expressions that include stream redirections where at least some of the file descriptors appear as variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

- `5<&"$fd"`: duplicate fd `$fd` onto fd 5 (where 5 is literal) in any Bourne-like shell (though beware that when yash is in posix mode, that won't work if `$fd` is not open for reading).
- `{fd}<&-`: close fd `$fd` in zsh, bash, ksh93

But you can't do `"$fd">anything` as you don't want `echo "$something">file` to not output the content of `$something` into `file` if that content just happens to contain only decimal digits.

In zsh, bash and ksh93, you can use `{fd}> something` for a fd above 9 to be allocated automatically and **stored** into `$fd`, but that's not what you're asking.

As far as I know, there's no other way than to use `eval`.

You can limit `eval` usage to the redirection only by using `exec`:

```
(eval "exec $TWO>&1"; exec date) >> logfile
```

It's the same situation in the `fish` shell.

It's also true in `rc` and derivatives, where the syntax is `>[3=5]`, and both fds have to be literal.